# How to design a snap/breakable PCB module?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design

I am designing a board which can be snapped (a part of the PCB could be broken off if not required):

[image: snap board]

Are there some design guidelines I should follow? What are the common rules (holes sizes and spacing) so the board can be snapped without too much strength but also not too easily?

Also, I saw some examples that uses two lines of stamp holes (e.g. the board below). Are there some advantages of doing that (e.g. reduced mechanical stress) other than having custom spacing between the boards?

[image: STM32G0316-DISCO]

Comment: @KingDuken I can see instances where it would be useful.

Comment: basically slots most of the way across and then drill holes spaced apart by their diameter for the last part. The line of holes cuts the strength in that region in half ensuring a clean break and reducing stress on non-breaking parts.

Comment: Brittle Ceramics must be in correct orientation and distance or they can crack.  Two methods well documented online  offset holes or V-score

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I also recommends [EEVblog #1037](https://youtu.be/QgKY5QWehME) on how to protect ceramics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method you show is known as "breakaway tabs" or "break-away tabs" or, more colloquially as "mouse bites".

If you search for guidelines you can find some useful documents, and references to an international standard- IPC-7351. That's not a free document but you may be able to find copies floating about on the net. You want Figure 3.21 (break-away tabs) and 3.20 (V-groove scoring).

They suggest, for a low-stress break-away, 5 holes per tab, 0.8mm diameter **unplated**, spaced 1.25mm apart, every 75mm along an edge with 1.2mm radius routed outlines. You can allow the routed radius to break into the holes.

Answer (score 2):

> Are there some design guidelines I should follow? What are the common
>   rules (holes sizes and spacing) so the board can be snapped without
>   too much strength but also not too easily?

Not really, breakable PCB's are more of an art (unless you have a mechanical engineer around with a structural FEM package). Usually what I do is try and get close to what I want on the prototype, and then adjust the hole size from there.

The more material you have between holes they harder it will be to break, if you have traces running across the pcb material between holes, you will also need to keep minimum clearance of the PCB manufacturer between holes/board edge and traces.

With one row of holes, the PCB material will break and can cause an edge with fiber glass material and epoxy, which might be bad for handling. The dual row holes in the bottom picture makes the break cleaner.

Also, some PCB manufacturers will do v-scoring, which makes for a clean break, but does not support traces running across the v-score.

[image]
Source: https://www.pcbway.com/pcb_prototype/PCB_V_Scoring.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you going to try to fabricate the board yourself?  Or will you be using an outside manufacturing house?

There are guidelines for doing what you want, but I do not know how universal they are.  We always consult with our PCB vendor and follow their recommendations given the size of the board, number of layers, stackup, thickness, etc.

I suggest you discuss this with your PCB vendor.

Comment: I use a well-known Chinese manufacturing house which is on the cheap side. Not sure if they have they have these kind of recommendations. Since it is for very low volume, I guess they don't waste their engineer time with hobby customers like me.

Comment: `Since it is for very low volume, I guess they don't waste their engineer time with hobby customers like me.` And you would absolutely be correct on that statement. It's the same for suppliers of parts as well. Unless you're making this device in bulk, manufacturers and suppliers won't waste their time in trying to help you out due to the lack of foreseeable large profit. "Nothing personal, just business."